# redirecting index.php urls on non-index.php urls

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo

my site's URLs open in both with and without index.php. see below:

```
www.example.com/index.php/en/support/download-center/softwares
www.example.com/en/support/download-center/softwares
```

how can i redirect URLs with index.php on the URLs without index.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the index.php out of the URL, you could try adding this to your .htaccess:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/`
`RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /$1 [R,L]`